# When to use mutex with iteration. c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vector, mutex

C++ provides very convinient way to traverse the container with iteration,

```
for(vector<int>::const_iterator p = c.begin(); p!=c.end();p++){}
```

but if when this is undergoing, someone `c.push_back(10)`.

Will it break the loop?

Should I use mutex every time I use container operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a race condition here.

If you are going to be using an STL container from multiple threads and at least one of those threads may modify the container, you need to synchronize access to the container.

The easiest way to go about doing this is to use a mutex.

Another option would be to find or implement a thread-safe container that provides the capabilities you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should, when  writes are possible from another threads.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html

> If multiple threads access a single container, and at least one thread may potentially write, then the user is responsible for ensuring mutual exclusion between the threads during the container accesses.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues.  First, you have an iterator invalidation issue.  Because `push_back` increases the size of the vector, it has the possibility of invoking an allocation.  whenever the capacity (not number of elements) of a vector changes, all iterators into the vector are invalidated.  This is easiest to deal with by making sure to call `reserve()` before beginning the loop to make sure there is enough space in the vector to satisfy all future `push_back` attempts while the loop runs.

The other issue, as mentioned in the other posts, you have a race condition when an insert may be running concurrently to the element being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to protect the whole vector with a mutex. And that is a good reason to dont use vectors to share data between threads. Most of the time we use queues, protecting push/pop with locks.

If you need to share data using big buffers, I would recommend using some kind of custom structure with "pages", so, you can block only a small part, and letting other threads run on different places of the memory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to lock before iteration and unlock after finishing

1. mutex lock
2. Iteration
3. mutex unlock